# Illegal invocation Error with Chrome and Closure

Tags: html5-canvas, closures, clojurescript

I have some Clojurescript code in order to set HTML5 Canvas line dashes. Since this is a typical case for cross-browser issues I want to first check, whether the Canvas Context objects has the attribute `setLineDash`, then call it (in order to avoid a attribute error etc.). I chose the `aget` syntax, since it prevents name munging.

```
(when (aget c "setLineDash")
  ((aget c "setLineDash") c dash))
```

The relevant line gets compiled by Google Closure, in "whitespace" mode:

```
 if(cljs.core.truth_(c["setLineDash"])) {
   c["setLineDash"].call(null, c, dash)
 }
```

and then in advanced optimization mode to:

`y(a.setLineDash) && a.setLineDash.call(m, a, c);`

So I feel like compilation is okay. `a` seems to be the munged name of c, `y` is probably `cljs.core.truth_`. The code works in Mozilla Firefox (both adv. and whitespace) and Google Chrome (whitespace). The advanced compilation does not work in Google Chrome due to a `TypeError`:

[image: Google Chrome Debug Window output]

This is kind of weird since `.setLineDash` is part of the object (and works in whitespace mode). My "feeling": Now what feels odd to me, is the parameter `m` of call. It is `null` and I wonder if this is the reason for this behaviour? In a way I am not too confident with the Javascript internals here to judge about this. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call `m` is in the place of the `this` argument of `fun.call`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now followed the approach of using [an extern.js file](http://lukevanderhart.com/2011/09/30/using-javascript-and-clojurescript.html) and declared `setLineDash` in there.

```
var CanvasRenderingContext2D = {};
CanvasRenderingContext2D.setLineDash = function() {};
```

Then I used

```
(when (..  c -setLineDash)
  (.. c (setLineDash dash)))
```

which compiles (advanced mode) to

```
y(a.setLineDash)&&a.setLineDash(c);
```

and this works (no `.call` weirdness).